# Select da linha com maior ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a tabela val_produtos, onde se tem *id_produto* e *valor_produto*, preciso dar um select * apenas na linha cujo a ID seja a maior, por exemplo, tenho dois produtos com ID's 1 e 2, porém preciso retornar nesse select apenas a linha com a ID 2. Tentei usar o *max(id_produto)*, porém ele dá erro se usado depois do where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma opção, para não utilizar sub queries, poderia ser ordenar decrescente por ID e retornar somente o registro **mais recente**

```
select * from val_produtos order by id desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de o fazer é assim

`Select * from val_produtos order by id DESC LIMIT 0, 1`

Assim irá apanhar o valor com a id mais alta

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer assim:

```
Select * from val_produtos where id_produto = (select max(id_produto) from val_produtos)
```

Um subselect que vai te retornar o id do maior

Comment: Não é necessário fazer um subselect, o ideal é ordenar pelo campo ID e limitar a consulta em 1 resultado.